# In verilog how to use variable 'i' of the "for loop"

Tags: for-loop, verilog

An error comes out that `Ki` & `Bi` is not declared; I want to use the loop variable in changing the array cell I'm filling:

```
module subbytes (C0,C1,C2,C3,A0,A1,A2,A3);

 input  [0:31] A0;
 input  [0:31] A1;
 input  [0:31] A2;
 input  [0:31] A3;
 wire [0:31] A0;
 wire [0:31] A1;
 wire [0:31] A2;
 wire [0:31] A3;

 output  [0:31] C0;
 output  [0:31] C1;
 output  [0:31] C2;
 output  [0:31] C3;
 reg   [0:31] C0;
 reg  [0:31] C1; 
 reg  [0:31] C2;
 reg  [0:31] C3;

 wire [0:7] K0 [0:3];
 wire [0:7] K1 [0:3]; 
 wire [0:7] K2 [0:3];
 wire [0:7] K3 [0:3];

 assign K0[0] = A0[0:7];
 assign K0[1] = A0[8:15];
 assign K0[2] = A0[16:23];
 assign K0[3] = A0[24:31];

 assign K1[0]=A1[0:7];
 assign K1[1]=A1[8:15];
 assign K1[2]=A1[16:23];
 assign K1[3]=A1[24:31];

 assign K2[0]=A2[0:7];
 assign K2[1]=A2[8:15];
 assign K2[2]=A2[16:23];
 assign K2[3]=A2[24:31];

 assign K3[0]=A3[0:7];
 assign K3[1]=A3[8:15];
 assign K3[2]=A3[16:23];
 assign K3[3]=A3[24:31];

 reg [2:0] i;
 reg [2:0] j;

 reg [0:7] B0 [0:3];
 reg [0:7] B1 [0:3];
 reg [0:7] B2 [0:3];
 reg [0:7] B3 [0:3];

 always @(*)
 begin
  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1 )
  begin
   for ( j = 0; j < 4; j = j + 1 )
   begin

    // Here is the problem 'Ki is not declared ' as

    case(Ki[j])
       0: Bi[j]=8'h63;
       1: Bi[j]=8'h7c;
       2: Bi[j]=8'h77;
       3: Bi[j]=8'h7b;
    /* ... other assignments to Bi[j] ... */
     252: Bi[j]=8'hb0;
     253: Bi[j]=8'h54;
     254: Bi[j]=8'hbb;
     255: Bi[j]=8'h16;
    endcase
   end
  end

  assign C0={B0[0],B1[0],B2[0],B3[0]};
  assign C1={B1[1],B2[1],B3[1],B0[1]};
  assign C2={B2[2],B3[2],B0[2],B1[2]};
  assign C3={B3[3],B0[3],B1[3],B2[3]};

 end

endmodule
```

Comment: If your not limited to verilog-95 there is no need to define your in/outputs 3 times. `module x(input wire [0:31] A0, output reg [0:31] C0);`  etc

Comment: Pretty sure you can not use case statement inside a for loop. NB: you have `assign` inside an always block which is not valid.

Comment: First off, You need brackets around the i: `K[i][j]`

Comment: `Ki is not declared` means that `Ki` is not declared. It's not complicated. What exactly is your question??

Answer (score 0):

`Ki` and `Bi` are never declared. Perhaps the SO is thinking the `i` in `Ki` corespondents to the `reg [2:0] i;`, which is false. I believe the SO want to reuse the case statement. If this is the case there are some options:

1. Move the case statement into its own sub module and instantiate appropriately.
2. Move the case statement into a function and call appropriately.
3. Merge `K1`,...`K3` into `K` with a large enough range and index appropriately. Same For `B`.
4. Switch to SystemVerilog where double unpacked arrays are allowed. Example, `K` can be defined as `logic [7:0] K [4][4];`